# Running msdos exe using python

Tags: python

I have a program written in MsDOS. I want to execute it with python on windows. On startup for example:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(
  ["C:\\Users\\\\SERVER.EXE"]
```

An incompatibility error occurs. Without python, I run it with an emulator.

How can I run it with python, are there any possibilities for this?

Comment: Well.. you have to run the emulator using subprocess..  First figure out how to run the msdos executable from a command line.. without python.  Then you'll be able to run it from python using subprocess using the same command string.

Comment: you need raw string `r'` - try with `r"C:\Users\somebody\SERVER.EXE"`

Comment: Can you show the full error you are getting?